# Unable to access Chrome Dino game using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate the Chrome dino game using Selenium in Python and have created this sample class:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


class GameControl():
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        self.DINO_URL="chrome://dino"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        self.driver.set_network_conditions(offline=True, latency=5, throughput=500 * 1024)
        self.actionChains = ActionChains(self.driver)

    def load_game(self):
        self.driver.get(self.DINO_URL)

    def close_game(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def start_game(self):
        print("Starting game...")
        self.actionChains.send_keys(Keys.SPACE).perform()
```

From another file, I call `load_game()`, but I get an error saying
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)`

When I repalce the url with a normal `https://google.com`, it seems to work fine. I'm assuming this might be because Selenium expects a response?

Is there a work-around for how I can access this game via Selenium?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched to the only version by a third party `https://chromedino.com/` and can access this.